# Bigcommerce API Webhooks with Ruby Gem Giving 404 Error

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, bigcommerce

I tried running the following command using the Bigcommerce API Ruby Gem:

```
puts Bigcommerce::Webhook.all
```

I receive the following error:

> [{"status":404,"message":"The requested resource was not found."}]

All other API commands work fine. Any idea why the webhooks are not working?

Comment: How many webhooks have you configured?

Comment: I haven't successfully created any yet.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The problem was that I was using the legacy API login, when I needed to use the oAuth API login via https / SSL.

Answer (score 0):

Since you haven't created any webhooks yet, the 404 resource is responding accurately as there is nothing to return in the list.